# How to refresh page with image showing when refreshing.. This doesn't work in IE :(

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried the below in Firefox and it works, but it doesn't in IE 7 and 8 -- the page refreshes but I don't get to see the image when refreshing in IE.
Thanks in advance.

Javascript:

```
window.onload = show;
function show() {
  document.getElementById("img444").style.display="none";
  setTimeout("hide()", 5000);  // 5 seconds
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("img444").style.display="block";
  window.location.reload(false);
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="img444" src="images/indicator.gif" style="display: none;"/>
```

Comment: @naijcoder , you are doing opposite in the function , function names says hide but it does show...

Comment: as gov pointed out swap "block" and "none" in your two functions. The first function.show is actually hiding the image and vice versa. This should work in both browsers. Let us know after fixing your functions whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well i changed the code as per @gov's comment and it does work on IE7 and firefox.

So it should also work for you

Comment: Thanks guys propbably too tired.:)
But if you test it on IE it refreshes continously wherease in Firefox it refreshes every 5 minutes why is this